# Vanilla JavaScript NPM web project starter

Tags: javascript, node.js, web, npm, toolchain

I'm looking for NPM toolset to help me to create baseline for Web projects with vanilla JS. So, as we set up Angular projects with angular-cli `ng init` command, React projects with `create-react-app`, is there any recommended NPM global tooling to set up all common toolchain (mainly Webpack, Babel and some development server with hot reloading/change detection) for non framework based projects?

Thank you for any suggestinos

Answer (score 2):

I'd look at [yeoman](http://yeoman.io/) and [available generators](http://yeoman.io/generators/) to pick one that suits your needs the most.

Here's a couple that might fit you:

- [webapp generator](https://github.com/yeoman/generator-webapp#readme)
- [babel boilerplate](https://github.com/babel/generator-babel-boilerplate)

Answer (score 0):

`grunt` provides [scaffolding](https://gruntjs.com/project-scaffolding).  There are templates available, or it's fairly easy to create your own.